# Respetar los espacios en el Arraylist y no sobrescribir

Tags: java, arraylist

mi código simula a la memoria RAM, estoy utilizando Arraylist para llenar mi ram de elementos, en el código el usuario podrá agregar o eliminar elementos en el vector, mi problema es cuando el usuario elimina un elemento, cuando ese elemento es eliminado será remplazado con el valor "0"
Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al agregar una nueva tarea que va hacer el reemplazo de esos 0 es decir si yo agrego un elemento de tamaño 3 entonces ese nuevo elemento ocupara tres 0 pero aveces tengo ceros separados uno del otro, y cuando yo quiero agregar un nuevo elemento ocupa tambien a los otros 0 por su tamaño

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puede hacer para que respete e los 0 separados uno del otro?

mi codigo:

```
public void asignarposicion(String m, int b)
{
    if(list.contains("0"))
    {
        
        int cont = 0;
        ListIterator<String> iterator = list.listIterator();
        do   
        {  
        String l = iterator.next();
        if(l.equals("0"))
        { 
            cont = cont +1;
            iterator.set(m);
        }
          
        }while(iterator.hasNext() && cont<b );
        
        
     
    }
    else {
    if(list.contains(m))
    {
        System.out.println("Tarea repetida, ingresa otra: ");
        n = leer.next();
        m = n;
    }
     for(i=0;i<b;i++)
     {
            
                  
                   if(list.size() <20)
                   {
                       list.add(i, m);   
                   }else {
                       System.out.println("Se alcanzo el limite de la memoria");
                       System.out.println("Ingresa nuevo tamaño:");
                       tam = leer.nextInt();
                       b = tam;
                   }
            
     }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Que buen problema tuviste, he creado una clase RAM2 la cual vendría a ser esta memoria RAM que tratas de simular.

Creas un objeto de tipo RAM2 y en tus acciones del menú, lo adaptas a esta clase.

Al crear un objeto de tipo RAM2 tendrás que agregar un limite para la memoria, este igual se puede modificar mediante un método, el código esta super explicado.

Agrega y elimina las tareas correctamente, al eliminar pide que le pases el nombre de la tarea por parámetro, la tarea sera remplazada por un "0", si se eliminan tareas entremedio por ejemplo:

Llenas la RAM de estas tareas: [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]

```
RAM.addTask("a", 1);
RAM.addTask("b", 1);
RAM.addTask("c", 1);
RAM.addTask("d", 1);
RAM.addTask("e", 1);
RAM.addTask("f", 1);
RAM.addTask("g", 1);
```

Y eliminas las tareas b,d,f, quedaria algo así: [a,0,c,0,e,0,g]

```
RAM.removeTask("b");
RAM.removeTask("d");
RAM.removeTask("f");
```

Como ves ahí hay ceros entre medio, pero aun asi si queres agregar
una tarea que ocupe todos esos espacios:

```
RAM.addTask("q", 3) //3 Son los espacios que quedan libres al eliminar 'b'd'f'
```

La memoria RAM remplazara los ceros por la nueva tarea de tipo "q" y quedaría así:

[a,q,c,q,e,q,g]

No se si solucionara tu problema, pero la clase funciona y creo es cuestión de adaptar tus acciones de menú a esta clase, o quizás puedas ver como lo hice y adaptarlo a tu programa, espero haberte ayudado :)

Los métodos utilizables que tiene esta clase son:

```
CAMBIA EL TAMAÑO DE LA RAM EN EJECUCIÓN
setLimitSize(int limit);

ELIMINA TODAS LAS TAREAS DE LA RAM
clear();

AGREGA UNA NUEVA TAREA A LA RAM CON
EL NOMBRE Y EL TAMAÑO DESEADO 
addTask(String name, int size);

ELIMINA LA TAREA CON X NOMBRE DE LA RAM
removeTask(String name);

IMPRIME LA MEMORIA RAM POR CONSOLA
printMemory();
```

Clase RAM2:

```
private class RAM2 {

    private ArrayList<String> task = new ArrayList<String>();

    private final String empty = "0"; // EL CARACTER DE "VACIO"

    private int limit = 0;

    /**
     * SE USA CADA VEZ QUE SE AGREGA O QUITA UNA TAREA,
     * TAMBIEN CUANDO SE LIMPIA LA RAM
     */
    private int used = 0;

    /**
     * CREA UNA NUEVA MEMORIA RAM CON EL
     * LIMITE DE LA MEMORIA ESTABLECIDO
     * POR EL PARAMETRO
     * 
     * @param limit
     */
    public RAM2(final int limit) {
        setLimitSize(limit);
        startEmptyRAM();
    }

    /**
     * RELLENA TODOS LOS ESPACIOS DE LA 
     * MEMORIA RAM EN "VACIO" - empty
     */
    private void startEmptyRAM() {
        for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
            task.add(empty);
        }
    }

    /*
     * CUANDO SE MODIFICA LA MEMORIA RAM EN TIEMPO DE EJECUCION,
     * SE ESTABLECE EL NUEVO LIMITE DE LA MEMORIA, ESTA NO PUEDE,
     * SER MAS CHICA QUE EL ANTERIOR LIMITE, SIEMPRE VA EN AUMENTO, 
     * 
     * CUANDO SE AUMENTA EL LIMITE, QUEDAN ESPACIOS VACIOS, LOS CUALES
     * HAY QUE LLENAR CON EL CARACTER VACIO (empty variable)
     * 
     * SE REALIZA UNA OPERACION RESTANDO EL TAMAÑO DE LA RAM ACTUAL, CON EL 
     * NUEVO LIMITE, DEVOLVERA EL NUMERO DE ESPACIOS POR RELLENAR
     * 
     * HACEMOS LA RESTA DE LOS ESPACIOS QUE FALTAN Y LOS AGREGAMOS
     */

    /**
     * ESTABLECE EL LIMITE DE ESTA
     * MEMORIA RAM
     * 
     * @param limit
     */
    public void setLimitSize(final int limit) {
        if(this.limit == 0) {
            this.limit = limit;
            return;
        }
    
        this.limit = limit;
    
        if(task.size() < limit) {
        
            int rest = limit - task.size();

            for (int i = 0; i < rest; i++) {
                task.add(empty);
            }
        
            return;
        }
    
        if(!(limit <= this.limit)) {
            System.err.println("El nuevo tamaño de la RAM es menor o igual al antiguo.");
            System.err.println("La memoria RAM solo puede aumentar su tamaño.");    
            return;
        }
    
    }

    /**
     * LIMPIA LA MEMORIA RAM, REMPLAZANDO
     * LAS TAREAS POR EL CARACTER DE VACIO
     */
    public void clear() {
        for (int i = 0; i < task.size(); i++) {
            task.set(i, empty);
        }
        used = 0;
    }

    /*
     * VERIFICACIONES EN ORDEN:
     * 
     * SI LA MEMORIA USADA ES MAYOR O IGUAL AL LIMITE EN EL
     * MOMENTO EN EL QUE SE AGREGA UNA NUEVA TAREA, ENTONCES
     * SIGNIFICA QUE SE HA ALCANZADO EL LIMITE DE LA MEMORIA
     * 
     * SI LA MEMORIA QUE LE QUEDA ES MENOR AL TAMAÑO DE LA TAREA
     * QUE ESTA ENTRANDO ENTONCES SE HA PASADO EL LIMITE DE 
     * LA MEMORIA RAM
     * 
     * SI LA MEMORIA QUE LE QUEDA ES MAYOR O IGUAL AL TAMAÑO DE LA TAREA
     * ENTONCES HAY ESPACIO PARA LA TAREA QUE ESTA ENTRANDO
     * 
     */

    /**
     * AGREGA UNA NUEVA TAREA A LA RAM, CON EL
     * NOMBRE Y EL TAMAÑO DE LA TAREA ESTABLECIDOS
     * POR LOS PARAMETROS
     * 
     * @param taskName
     * @param size
     */
    public void addTask(final String taskName, final int size) {
        if(task.contains(taskName)) {
            System.err.println("Tarea repetida, debe ingresar otra.");
            return;
        }
    
        // AL LIMITE
        if(used >= limit) {
            System.err.println("Se alcanzo el limite de la memoria RAM.");
            return;
        }
    
        // SE RE PASO
        if(limit-used < size) {
            System.err.println("Has sobrepasado el limite de la memoria RAM.");
            return;
        }
    
        if(limit-used >= size) { // HAY ESPACIO
            int replaced = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < task.size(); i++) {
                if(task.get(i).equals(empty)) {
                
                    if(replaced == size) {
                        return;
                    }
                
                    replaced++;
                    task.set(i, taskName);
                
                    used++;
                }    
            }
        
            return;
        }

    }

    /**
     * ELIMINA UNA TAREA EXISTENTE CON X NOMBRE, 
     * SI ESTA NO SE ENCUETRA LANZARA UN MENSAJE 
     * POR CONSOLA.
     * 
     * @param taskName
     */
    public void removeTask(final String taskName) {
        if(task.contains(taskName)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < task.size(); i++) {
                if(task.get(i).equals(taskName)) {
                    task.set(i, empty);
                
                    used--;
                }
            }
            return;
        }
        System.err.println("Esa tarea no existe.");
    }

    /**
     * IMPRIME TODOS LOS EPACIOS USADOS MEDIANTE
     * LA CONSOLA
     */
    public void printMemory() {
        System.out.println(task.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: Gracias :D, voy a tratar de adaptarlo.